# Do I need to ground fluorescent bulbs to get them to light up using a tesla coil?

Tags: electric-fields

I want to create a demonstration to show the wireless electricity effect from a Tesla Coil. I know that fluorescent bulbs light up with people holding them up near the tesla coil, but if I wanted to create a display on a wall using fluorescent lights would the tubes need to be grounded for it to work? If so how should I do this? If not, why? i.e. how is the circuit being completed?

Comment: I suspect you will find that they light more reliably if there is a ground strap of sorts around the glass tube, maybe a quarter of the way from one end.  The Tesla coil/fluorescent light thing is 50% black magic, even to the folks who understand it.

Answer (score 1):

They do not have to be grounded. The tesla coil produces oscillating electric field, the stronger the higher the end of the wire of the secondary coil. This electric field itself can make the gas inside the lamp produce EM radiation. There is no need to have 'circuit completed' in the common sense, with wires. The energy flows from the coil to the lamp without any wires.